# Slide to delete like android in UITableVIew iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement "slide to delete" table cell functionality. This should show red color when cell is slide & delete row on full slide. This is same as in android list & gmail app slide to archive feature. Has anyone implemented this?

Comment: have you checked [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)

Comment: @MrugeshTank - MGSwipeTableCell & SWTableViewCell allows to set more options for left or right when we swipe. I dont want to show any button options. On swipe table view, it should simply delete cell.

Comment: Why down vote.?? this is clearly not found anywhere on research. This feature is there in gmail app & paytm app. Without research i will not ask any question..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set editing to yes for your tableview and you have to implement `canEditRowAtIndexPath` and `commitEditingStyle` delegate of your table view like :

In `viewDidload`,

```
   [yourTableView setEditing:YES];
```

and your delegates should be like,

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        // here you can delete object from your datasource(array) also if needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is default delete feature. Please read my question thourouly. I dont want this default behaviour. I dont want to show any button options. On swipe table view, it should simply delete cell